# Air travel risk vs taxi risk

Tags: aviation, vehicle

When a person expresses fear about air travel, often somebody will helpfully explain that there is more chance of being killed in a vehicle accident in the taxi on the way to the airport than in an air accident once on board per source [here](http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/space/how-risky-is-flying.html) and [here](http://anxieties.com/flying-howsafe.php#.Vl1Tc9IrLIU).

Is the typical taxi ride to the airport really more dangerous than the flight itself?

Comment: *Very* related: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5581/are-airplanes-the-safest-mode-of-transportation

Comment: [This](https://youtu.be/zcZXG4KGri8?t=58s) better establishes the notability of the claim.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. One is more likely to be killed on the drive to the [airport](http://anxieties.com/flying-howsafe.php#.Vl1Tc9IrLIU) than on a flight on an airline with a good safety record.

Rail and plane travel are much safer in terms of annual and lifetime odds than road travel when calculated in terms of deaths and total [population](http://www.medicine.ox.ac.uk/bandolier/booth/Risk/trasnsportpop.html). 
The [odds](http://www.statisticbrain.com/airplane-crash-statistics/) of being killed on a single airline flight are 1 in 29.4 million. The [OAG](http://www.planecrashinfo.com/cause.htm) Aviation & PlaneCrashInfo.com accident database calculates odds of fatality for an individual on one of the 39 safest airliners at 1 in 10 million. However, by comparison, on the 39 airlines with the worst records, the odds are calculated to be more than 10 times greater at 1 in 1.5 million.

Still, a motor vehicle occupant's accidental death risk per year during a drive are 1 out of 7,700 referring to U.S. Department of [Transportation](http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/space/how-risky-is-flying.html). The lifetime odds of a motor vehicle accident is 1:112 referring to National Safety [Council](http://www.nsc.org/learn/safety-knowledge/Pages/injury-facts-chart.aspx).

2. "Mile to Mile" comparison of different modes of transportation show that travel by air has the same fatality rate as driving, but a much lower fatal accident rate (by a large number of fatalities per accident).

The fatality rates calculated by [Mereterix](http://www.meretrix.com/~harry/flying/notes/safetyvsdriving.html) for driving is 1.32 fatal accidents and 1.47 fatalities per 100 million miles (for 2014, the fatality rate fell to a record-low of 1.07 deaths per 100 [million](http://www.nhtsa.gov/About+NHTSA/Press+Releases/2015/2014-traffic-deaths-drop-but-2015-trending-higher) vehicle miles traveled) and airlines is .05 fatal accidents and 1.57 fatalities per 100 million miles.

Comment: I would really, really like to see uncertainties to those numbers. The whole answers could be suffering from the "false precision" fallacy.

Comment: I'm having trouble mapping from your claims to the sources provided. (For example: Who says there is one fatality in 8 million trips? I can't figure which reference is supposed to support that.) Quoting directly from the sources would help.

Comment: @Oddthinking-added the source for motor vehicle accident numbers!

Comment: Which are per year, not per trip. :-(

Comment: Just confirming I'm reading the last paragraph correctly: about 26 times less likely to have a fatal accident, but about the same average number of deaths.